# I want to remove the reference on facebook page

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to remove the application reference apearing on facebook login page.

Comment: Make you picture smaller please. Its 440Kb !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible ! You don't have the control on that.  It's a security requirement enforced by Facebook that let the user knows to who's he is granting rights.